# how to get modified content as android layout xml file?

Tags: android, xml, copy

I have implemented an application for modify the xml layout with some properties.
I have designed an xml file at R.layout.main.

I am setting Visibility property from my activity class.When i update main.xml file at run time i would like to get copy of main.xml file with updated property as Visibility as gone

Initially the main.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

//Here i did not set the android:visibility="gone"
  //I would like to change the above property from activity class

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question1" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/questioncheckBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextone"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="true">
    </EditText>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have implemented my application as follows:

```
   public class ContentExmpleActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout l1,l2;
CheckBox c1,c2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    l1 =((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1));
    l2=((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2));
    c1=((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
    c2=((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2));

    c1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    c2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Implementation for get the modified content xml layout with properties from emulator

        }
    });


}
 }
```

from the above class i am hidding layout when user check the check box then it is hidding.When user click on save button i would like to get the contentView xml file as android layout xml.i mean copy of the main.xml with modified properties as hiding layout properties.

How can i get copy of main.xml file when the content has modified?

please any body help me.....

Comment: You can't actually get the modified xml file, maybe you should explain what are trying to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

by

```
View vi = View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
setContentView(vi);
```

Now, you have a reference of your modified view and you can assign it where you want.

Comment: this is not my answer.my question is i would like to get the copy of xml file for redesign.

Comment: i mean i would like to get xml file regard modified xml